# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required) react, node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I'm working on an old full stack project based in react front end and node/sequelize on the back end.  When I start both front and back end on the back end, my project locally cannot grab any data from the back end.

Instead of grabbing all the relevant data needed to produce the page, when the front end tries to read the needed data from tables, I see error 426.  I also see uncaught promises printing out the following.

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
Response
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
false
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
426
statusText
: 
"Upgrade Required"
type
: 
"basic"
```

I've resetted the database, checked to see if there we're any errors on my backend and no errors show up.  I've cleared the majority of the warnings on the front end console as well.  I've looked up on google for hours as well as any past questions being posted, but anything to error 426 pertains to web sockets and there is nothing stating in my errors that I have a socket issue when my front and back end ports are activated.  If anyone knows a way to deal with this bug I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does the server send the `Upgrade` header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426 - *The server sends an Upgrade header with this response to indicate the required protocol(s).*

Comment: For any type of request sent over the response is 426, I'm not seeing any required protocols when I open up and inspect the uncaught promises.